# Javascript; function (x,y,z), confused on how values are passed

Tags: javascript, function, return

I searched and read about functions to no extent. I have seen my questions answered, but not in the detail I have understood. I'm less than one year into programming.
Okay, so I don't understand how the r,c,or the e get values.
How does Javascript know what to use "r" and "c" for when the code is later called. How does the "e" end up in the final function?
Maybe I'm shooting too high trying to understand this, but maybe not. Thanks

```
game.makeKeydown = function (r, c) {
    return function (e) {
        return game.onKeydown(e, r, c);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a technique called [currying (partial function application)](http://ejohn.org/blog/partial-functions-in-javascript/).

So you have a function `game.onKeydown` that takes three parameters.  You want a function with one parameter, because you know two of the parameters now.  The values `r` and `c` get assigned local values inside `makeKeydown`, and the value `e` gets assigned when the new function `makeKeydown` is actually invoked.

The link above is an article by John Resig talking about currying (recommended).

Comment: All the answers helped, thanks all... This one is hitting the nail on the head for terms that meet my understanding.

Comment: Whoops, sorry... I am learning the site.    So this code will put the value of row and col into c,r    """ elem.onkeydown = game.makeKeydown(row, col);"""

Comment: Great, thanks. Good article too! I can follow functions much more easily now. I hope I can start to apply them more effectively, shouldn't be long.

Answer (score 1):

The `r` and `c` variables are determined at the time that `game.makeKeydown` is called.  For example `var fn = game.makeKeydown(1, 2);` will return a function for which the values of `r` and `c` is always 1 and 2, respectively.

`fn` will also accept one value, which will become the value of `e`, so `fn("s")` will give the value `"s"` to `e`.

By the way, the mechanism that's assigning the values to `r` and `c` is called a "closure".

Comment: Thank you, now I know what to search for to get more in depth =)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty amateur, but this is my understanding of this: When you pass parameters into a function, the function will then replace all instances of the variable that you used to name your parameter with the value that you pass as a parameter. So what this function is doing is creating a function with fixed values of r and c, as well as an additional parameter, e, which you can later pass through this new function that you have just created.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Sometimes, an amateur will be able to help a rookie better than a pro can. You are exactly right with your answer too, for some reason I was able to understand the first one a little better.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, the code you have is a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures). The inner function is constructed and returned when the outer function is called. Thus, when the outer function `makeKeydown` is called with arguments `r` and `c`, they are available at the time the inner function is being constructed.

the inner function will take only one argument, `e` which probably may be the event object that is passed to the event handler. Thus,

`game.makeKeyDown( 2, 4 )` will return a function which can be saved in a `var`. This new function will be called with only one arguments as follows:

`var handler = game.makeKeydown(1,2);`

`var result = handler(4)`